# Most efficient way filtering an array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

I have a array of arrays as follows:

```
var masterArray = [
   ["String", "String", "String", "1"],
   ["String", "String", "String", "2"],
   ["String", "String", "String", "3"],
   ...
]
```

Last element of each array is an Int String.

What would be the most efficient way of filtering the master array into 3 arrays based on the last element of each array?

Of course I can do smth like this:

```
var filteredArray1 = [[String]]()
var filteredArray2 = [[String]]()
var filteredArray3 = [[String]]()

for anArray in masterArray {
   if anArray[3] == "1" {
      filteredArray1.append(anArray) 

   } else if anArray[3] == "2" {
      filteredArray2.append(anArray) 

   } else if anArray[3] == "3" {
      filteredArray3.append(anArray) 

   } 
}
```

But I think there should be a more efficient way of achieving this, maybe with filters or predicates? I just can't figure out how to pin-point that last element of each array.

**Edit**

Just to give an example of what in my opinion is an efficient way of filtering.

In a different unrelated use case, I have an array of CoreData entities tagRecords. In this case, as I know that each entity has dateStart property, I can easily filter it with NSPredicate like so:

```
let currentPred = NSPredicate(format: "dateStart >= %@ && dateStart <= %@", argumentArray: [currentMonth.startOfMonth(), currentMonth.endOfMonth()])
                
let filteredRecords = tagRecords.filter { currentPred.evaluate(with: $0) }
```

Comment: `var aDictionary1 = [[String]]()` that's misleading, because it's an array of array, not a Dictionary. What's your final goal? Maybe use custom struct/model instead? Why not have a `let final: [[[String]]]` instead of 3 arrays? How do you use the array?

Comment: @Larme you are absolutely right, sorry for confusion, updated accordingly. In terms of final goal - data from each filtered array is simply shown on a UITableView which is filtered using UISegmentedControl

Comment: I don't know what you expect in terms of being "more efficient". You are taking a single pass through the array and you can't do better than that. You need to look at every single element to figure out what bucket they belong to. There is just no good way around it. If you are just looking to reduce the lines of code, there are options like [groupToMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupToMap)

Comment: @sinanspd added an example of what I think is an efficient filtering, does that make sense?

Comment: Admittedly I dont fully understand your use case but it seems to me that your are overcompleting this. In terms of time, no, I don't think this is faster than the for loop. For a few reasons 1) String evaluation for that predicate is insanely expensive 2) Filter creates a shallow copy of the array. 3)[filter](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.filter) perform a lot of extra things like type casting. All that said, I also dont think the difference'll be noticeable unless you have a million elements in that array, in which case JS is the wrong language

Comment: Thanks @sinanspd would you recommend using for loop approach or below suggested way of extraction via keys from dictionary if that masterArray would have 2-3K arrays in it?

Comment: You mentioned a Table view in the UI above. How is this data displayed? Is it unstructured at first and you press a tab to display specific groups? or does it start in the grouped state?

Comment: It starts in the grouped state. The filtering will happen in viewWillAppear or, depending on time needed for filtering, I might have to start with an activity indicator on a blank view and then reload tableView once the data is filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two step solution is to group the data into a dictionary and then extract each array from it using the keys (which I assume are given)

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: masterArray, by: \.last)

let filteredArray1 = grouped["1", default: []]
//...
```

Comment: Thanks @Joakim Danielson just did a quick test and this actually does what I needed. The only thing is that right now I do not have actual data for that masterArray which is expected to be something around 2-3K arrays each of 6 relatively small strings, would you recommend using this approach instead of for loop?

Comment: Why don’t you run some tests and compare?